# Sharepoint list column uppercase validation

Tags: list, validation

So I'm basically trying to validate a column in my SharePoint list to have a Specific letter as the starting character of the field. I'm running into an issue with capitalization. I need the first character to be only uppercase. This is what I currently have but it is not validating for only uppercase. (67 is the ascii code for the letter "c"). Thank you!

```
CODE(MID([Column Name],1,1)=UPPER(67))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=CODE(MID([Column Name],1,1))=67
```

or

```
=CODE(LEFT([Column Name],1))=67
```

CODE returns a number.